# Why is my ConditionOperator.In with string values resulting in SQL with int values?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm writing a QueryExpression with a Filter using the ConditionOperator.In operator and passing strings as the values.  However, using trace on the CRM server, I'm able to view the SQL generated, and it's replacing my strings with "1, 2, 3".

Specifically, this code:

```
var filter = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
filter.AddCondition("primaryobjecttypecode", ConditionOperator.In, "account", "contact");

var query = new QueryExpression("sdkmessagefilter")
{
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("primaryobjecttypecode"),
    Criteria = filter,
    LinkEntities =
        {
            new LinkEntity()
            {
                 LinkFromEntityName = "sdkmessagefilter",
                 LinkFromAttributeName =  "sdkmessageid",
                 LinkToEntityName = "sdkmessage",
                 LinkToAttributeName = "sdkmessageid",
                 Columns = new ColumnSet("name"),                              
             },                                                       
         }
 };

 var response = orgProxy.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

Results in this SQL:

```
select top 5001 
    "sdkmessagefilter0".PrimaryObjectTypeCode as "primaryobjecttypecode",
    "sdkmessage1".Name as "sdkmessage1.name" 
from
    SdkMessageFilter as "sdkmessagefilter0" 
    join SdkMessage as "sdkmessage1" 
       on ("sdkmessagefilter0".SdkMessageId  =      "sdkmessage1".SdkMessageId) 
where
    ((("sdkmessagefilter0".PrimaryObjectTypeCode in (1, 2)))) 
order by "sdkmessagefilter0".SdkMessageFilterId asc
```

Ultimately, this results in a SqlException due to a failure to case "1" as a string.

**Why is are {"account", "contact"} string values turning into {1, 2} int values?**

I'm running Dynamics CRM 2011 UR 10 on the server and my app is using SDK 5.0.9689.2166

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the column you are using in your filter is an `int` data type.

`primaryobjecttypecode` holds a number that represents a given type of entity - the entity type code.

1 is account, 2 is contact.

[Entity Type Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb887791.aspx)

> Type codes below 10,000 are reserved for Microsoft Dynamics CRM system
>   entities. Custom entities have a value greater than or equal to
>   10,000. Note that custom entity object type codes may change during
>   import and are not guaranteed to be the same between systems.
>
> You can retrieve the type codes for all entities by using the
>   RetrieveAllEntities message.

So if you are only going to use system entities you will probably get away with:

`filter.AddCondition("primaryobjecttypecode", ConditionOperator.In, 1, 2);`

Or if you are going to use custom entities, you will have to query the CRM metadata or store the values in configuration somewhere.